# Python Program to Sum of each Row and each Column of a Matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a Python script to calculate the x value and y value (like matrix).
content of "budget.txt" file:

```
Budget Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Sum
Milk      10  20   31   52   7      11
Eggs     1    5    1     16    4      58
Bread    22  36  17    8   21    16
Butter    4    5    8    11   36     2
Total
```

The script will calculate the budget.txt file and show results in column "Sum" and Row "Total".
Here is my code:

```
import sys

budget_file = sys.arvg[1]
df = open(budget_file).read()
print(df)
```

Output: I can read the file. Now my question is how to sum the values of row and column-wise?

Comment: @Aktar Can you please explain what do you mean by "The script will calculate the budget.txt file and show results in column "Sum" and Row "Total"." What exactly is the desired outcome you want? sum each row and show the result in column Sum? what does Total show? just sum of all values?

Comment: Hi Omri,
I want the script to calculate each row value and show the result in the "Sum" column section like X and each column value and show the result in the "Total" row section.

Answer (score 0):

Given your dataframe, I would approach the calculations in two steps:

1. Compute the Sum of each row of the data frame (see [How To Sum DataFrame Rows](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-sum-rows-of-a-pandas-dataframe-in-python)
2. Compute the Sum of each Column

Given the following dataframe:

```
        Budget  Jan     Feb     Mar     Apr     May     Jun
0   Milk    10  20  31  52  7   11
1   Eggs    1   5   1   16  4   58
2   Bread   22  36  17  8   21  16
3   Butter  4   5   8   11  36  2
```

To Compute the Sum across the rows of a dataframe

```
#list  columns to sum across
df['Sum'] = df[list(df.columns)[1:]].sum(axis=1)
```

This produces the following df:

```
    Budget  Jan     Feb     Mar     Apr     May     Jun     Sum
0   Milk    10.0    20.0    31.0    52.0    7.0     11.0    131.0
1   Eggs    1.0     5.0     1.0     16.0    4.0     58.0    85.0
2   Bread   22.0    36.0    17.0    8.0     21.0    16.0    120.0
3   Butter  4.0     5.0     8.0     11.0    36.0    2.0     66.0
```

To add a row with the sum of all columns:

```
df.append(pd.Series(df.sum(),name='Total'))
```

This will yield a dataframe like:

```
    Budget  Jan     Feb     Mar     Apr     May     Jun     Sum
0   Milk    10  20  31  52  7   11  262.0
1   Eggs    1   5   1   16  4   58  170.0
2   Bread   22  36  17  8   21  16  240.0
3   Butter  4   5   8   11  36  2   132.0
Total   MilkEggsBreadButter     37  66  57  87  68  87  804.0
```

If the string summation under budget is bothersome you can reset that specific cell to an empty string.